# passing parameter to a jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery function that is used by two different buttons.

Is there a way to pass a parameter to the function so I can tell it what  needs to be written to?

My function starts like this:

```
 $("#tblOwnerSearchResults, #tblDirectorSearchResults").on("click", "input.select", function () {
```

And I need to pass a variable to this part:

```
$(html).appendTo('**#A_Table**');
```

Thanks!

Comment: in the function `this.id` is the id of the clicked element.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? How is `#A_Table` related to the button clicked? Can you navigate from `this` to the target element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet might be to store the variable directly in the elements using `data-` attributes and retrieving it using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method.

example HTML:

```
<input class="select" data-str="something">
```

example jQuery:

```
$("#tblOwnerSearchResults, #tblDirectorSearchResults").on("click", "input.select", function () {
    var str = $(this).data('str');
    $(html).appendTo(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML attribute. For example.

```
<a id="tblOwnerSearchResults" data-parameter="foo">Button</a>
```

And the jQuery

```
$(this).data("parameter");
```

Comment: Or use `.data()`, since that's what it's for.

Comment: Prefer `$(this).data("parameter")`

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you can check which element triggered the event:

```
$this.attr('id');
```